# RDS PostgreSQL - Selective data transfer from a table to another table in another region

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, restore

I've an setup of **2 postgreSQL RDS** running in **2 different regions** in AWS. Both the RDS don't have public access, so it can be accessed only inside the **respective VPC**. Both the RDS have the same DB and table structure, which means same number of Databases, tables, schemas etc... with same structure

Here some-point in time I need to move some data from table **table_b** in **RDS B** to **table_b** in **RDS A**. (Moving data to the same table so there won't be any issues in the table structure with the data.) Since the RDS are running in different VPC's and doesn't have public access I can't transfer the data directly.

I tried to take a snapshot of the **RDS B** and exported it to s3 and from s3 converted the ***.parquet** format into ***.sql** and using an **lambda** in the **same region** as **RDS A** took only the table I want and inserted the data into the **RDS A**.

All went well until there is no complex data. My **lambda** read the data type of the column string or number **dynamically** and inserted into the destination table. When there are tables with json array I'm facing issues in casting the data.

Is this the right approach to full fill my requirement or is there any other better & secured method to do it?

Comment: Can this be a manual operation? If so, I'd recommend [Exporting data from an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance to Amazon S3 - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html), then [Importing data from Amazon S3 into an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html). It can be automated, but would need an SQL connection to each RDS database to execute the commands.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeah I can assign proper permissions to automate this. But my question is that can the importing data from s3 can append the existing table which already has some data?

Comment: Yes, the import process makes use of the [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 15: COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command that **appends** data to the table.